# Putting parentheses around label value in ArcGIS for Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.3, labeling, attribute-table

How can I create a label expression to put parentheses around an attribute value I need labeled on a map?

I'm using ArcGIS version 10.3.

Comment: what GIS software are you using?

Comment: I'm using ArcGIS version 10.3.  I tried the recommendations listed below and it work:)  Thanks for your assistance.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In your label expression enter:

`"(" & FieldName & ")"`

where `FieldName` is the name of the field you're trying to label.  Double-click the field from the fieldlist to ensure it enters the field name in the correct format.

Answer (score 2):

In QGIS:

```
 '(' || "FIELDNAME" || ')'
```

Comment: @andrew2016 great! please mark that as your answer if you can! have fun!

Comment: To the down-voters - this answer was provided before we were told of the GIS software used, so was appropriate in the circumstance.